# Google Forms and Sheets - Finding student averages from Google Form input

Tags: google-sheets

I am a high school teacher. I am teaching a food class and each week my students prepare a recipe with a group. After each "food lab" I ask them to fill out an evaluation from in a Google Doc, where they give a grade out of 15.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58gPH.png) Students complete a self-evaluation for themselves and also one for each of the other group members (peer evaluation). Looking at each of these documents and then calculating averages is too much work. I would like to create a Google Form to input the student names and scores and then have a linked Google Sheet do the calculations for me.

Here are some important points to keep in mind:

- The composition (who is working together) of the groups may change week to week due to absences
- Groups usually consist of 3 students, but could be 2 or 4 (again, depending on absences)
- The final grade for each "food lab" will be an average of the score from the student's self-evaluation and each score attributed to them from their peers in their group

Although it is a bit awkward, I think that best strategy for getting the student names into the form responses is to create a dropdown box type question that opens up to list all the students in the class. I described this as "awkward" just because the list may be long, perhaps up to 26 names. Having students choose the names of their group members from a list is advantageous because it will eliminate the possibility (if using a "short-answer" type question) of students misspelling a name of a group member and consequently not having the score associated with the correct person.

It makes senses to use "scale" questions to input the scores.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSdnL.png)

I don't have any problem creating the Google Form and sending the data to Google Sheets. I am pretty good at setting up formulas and formatting in Sheets, but don't have much experience manipulating data imported from a Google Form. I will need Sheets to be able to group (or at do a calculation by finding the self-evaluation and the peer evaluations relating to each individual student and then find the average of these scores.

Example: I fill out the self-evaluation and give myself 14/15. I work with Abdul and Mark. Abdul gave me 15/15 and Mark gave me 13/15. The average of these 3 scores (42/3)is 14. Sheets will need to associate these scores as belonging to one student and find the average.

It would be ideal if each time students filled out an evaluation for a food lab that another sheet is created in the same Google Sheet. If then there was a way to average (or just add  up) each student's grade from each food lab each week so it could be reported as one final grade, that would be awesome.

Hoping someone can help me out with this.

Thanks,
Rodney

I have successfully created a Google Form to accomplish this, but I am lost at how to bring this data together in Sheets to get the right calculations.

Comment: The average for each person in the group is easy: sum of the grades received / (number of students in the group - 1). The interesting bit is how to account for those who did not submit grades for others, do you allow them to receive the grades from their project partners or since they gave nothing they get nothing. Lots of fun evaluating the results depending on decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with some screenshots. I hope this helps! I'm assuming that the students redo the google form for each member of their group + themselves, and also that all the responses are collected during class (so that the form response timestamps for one food lab all match with one single day).

1. In the sheet where the responses collect, you can add three columns: one for the total mark out of 15 given to the student based on the form responses to the 5 questions, and another two that just split the timestamp into the date and time. I recreated your google form, and in the picture below have the form response sheet. It should look similar to the one you will have. The columns you need to add are in green:
   [image: Form response sheet]

The formula in cell I2 is simply `=SUM(C2:G2)`, and the formula in cell J2 is `=split(A2, " ")` [note: once you type in this formula, it will automatically create the third K column]. You then just need to drag these formulas down to cover the other form response rows like in the image above.

2. Now in the same Google Sheet but in a separate sheet, you can have a row of all the students' names (as they are written in the form response drop down), and the date of each food lab. You can now have their average score for each food lab in this table, with each row corresponding to a different food lab. Here is a picture:

[image: Analysis sheet]

The food lab dates are self-entered by you (column A). The names of each class member (row 2) are also self-entered by you, but as mentioned before come from the same list you used to create the quiz drop down list so that the formula can check for an exact match.

The formula for cell B3 is: `=AVERAGEIFS('Form Responses 1'!$I:$I,'Form Responses 1'!$B:$B, B$2, 'Form Responses 1'!$J:$J, $A3)` .
This formula averages the scores for each student (the ones in column I of the collected form responses sheet), by filtering the collected responses by the relevant name, and making sure the form response comes from the correct food lab date in column A. The formula for cell B3 can then be dragged across for all students and all food lab dates.

Then you can get the overall average across all food labs for each student by averaging each student's column (so assuming you had some more food lab scores on other dates in rows 4 and 5, the formula in cell B6 would be `=AVERAGE(B3:B5)`).

I hope this answer makes sense and is useful! It will work for groups of any size and composition week to week.